# Get SQL string from Linqkit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linqkit

how can I return the SQL from a `LinqKit.ExpandableQuery<T>`?
I'm using the code from [stevefenton.co.uk](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/07/getting-the-sql-query-from-an-entity-framework-iqueryable/) but it seems to fail at

```
private static System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T> GetQueryFromQueryable<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            var internalQueryField = query.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_internalQuery")).FirstOrDefault();
            var internalQuery = internalQueryField.GetValue(query);
            var objectQueryField = internalQuery.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.Name.Equals("_objectQuery")).FirstOrDefault();
            return objectQueryField.GetValue(internalQuery) as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery<T>;
        }
```

with the `internalQueryField` being null.

It has something to do with the inheritance tree (LinqKit + Linq), but I can't
get my head around it.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string sql = query.ToString();
```

Comment: when a programmer brain hangs he/she would do strange things, I have done it many times, no worry ;)

Comment: i was so convinced it would not work that I didn't even try :)

Comment: This does not seem to work in .Net core 2.2. You just get a reflection string i.e. "value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[my.object.typehere])"